# Calculate price of rental with different periods of pricing wordpress & woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Hello I'm working on a woocommerce car rental shop and I have the following issue that I'm trying to fix.
Given the following case:
A client comes to rent a car with a date period of October 29 11:00 to November 12 11:00 with a total of 15 days of rentals.
The base price of a car for rent is 17 euros/day with an extra fee of 5 euros/day for October and 17 euros/day with an extra fee of 10 euros/day for November.
So now I have the following dump that shows the same example :

```
Base Price: 17
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [fee] => 5.00
            [days] => 3
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [fee] => 10.00
            [days] => 12
        )

)
```

When I do the math I'm getting 66 euros for first period 29 October to 31 October and 324 euros for 1 November - 12 November period with a total of 390 euro.
If I were to do an average price 390 / 15 and then set that as price for the car the total would be incorrect.
How could I change the way wocommerce calculates total to calcule the price for the car + other options for rental. ?

Comment: First you have to know how many days left from current month then next month
so October is 3 days x 5 + 17 and 12 days x 10   = 32 + 120 = 152 euro. I dont know how u define prices for each month so i hope this will give you idea.

Comment: If fee is for more than 1 day count total days - 1 so 2 days x 5 + 17 and 12 days x 10   = 27 + 120 = 147 euro.

Comment: thank you for your comments as i've stated in another comment the problem is that when woocommerce will calculate the total price doesn't know how to use both prices if I were to use the pricing as per array example. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a realy basic example

```
$price = '17.00';
$period_range = array(
    '10' => array(
        'fee' => 5.00,
        'days' => 3
    ),
    '11' => array(
        'fee' => 10.00,
        'days' => 12
    )
);
$charge = array();
foreach($period_range as $range) {
    $charge[] = round($range['fee'] * $range['days']);
}

$total = array_sum($charge) + $price;
echo $total;
//this will return 152
```

Comment: thank you for the example. But my issue is that I'm not sure how to change the wordpress total to use both prices.